# Mail sending -SMTP error with javaMailSender

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I am running a program to send email using spring boot with gmail smtp.
The same code works fine in my personal laptop.
But when I try to run it in office laptop it doesn't work and says
SMTP timeout:

> Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;

I feel it is because of firewall or proxy.
I tried to check from Outlook but could not get smtp name , i tried some hit and trial also.
Any possible solution.

Comment: Yes..Mostly this is because the firewall is not allowing to connect. You can confirm that with commands like- #ping smtp.gmail.com #telnet smtp.gmail.com 587..If you are unable to connect, only option is to get system admin's help

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#condebug).